# VBA user-form code only works when sheet is visible

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm sure I've just made a school boy error but i just can't see it :(
I have a user form that searches a worksheet(sheet 2) and displays the results in a list box but the code will only work when excel is visible and the sheet being searched selected. Any advice would be greatly received :)

```
Private Sub Branch_Search_Button_Click()
'branch search
Dim rownum As Long
Dim searchrow As Long

Sheet5.Range("A2:C9999").ClearContents
rownum = 2
searchrow = 2
Do Until Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 1).Value = ""
    If InStr(1, Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 2).Value, TextBox1.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Sheet5.Cells(searchrow, 1).Value = Cells(rownum, 1).Value
        Sheet5.Cells(searchrow, 2).Value = Cells(rownum, 2).Value
        Sheet5.Cells(searchrow, 3).Value = Cells(rownum, 3).Value
        searchrow = searchrow + 1
    End If
    rownum = rownum + 1
Loop

If searchrow = 2 Then
    MsgBox "Area not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

ListBox2.RowSource = "Area_Search!a1:c" & Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
End Sub
```

That was it! thanks for your help Super Symmetry really appreciated!!! :D

Comment: Try to qualify **all** ranges. E.g. `Cells(rownum, 1).Value` should be `Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 1).Value`. `Range("c" & Rows.Count)` should be `Sheet5.Range("c" & Rows.Count)`.  (change `Sheet2` and `Sheet5` appropriately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential solution**

You should fully qualify **all** your ranges. The following might fix your error. Please note the comments starting with `'*`

```
Private Sub Branch_Search_Button_Click()
'branch search
Dim rownum As Long
Dim searchrow As Long

    Sheet5.Range("A2:C9999").ClearContents
rownum = 2
searchrow = 2
Do Until Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 1).Value = ""
    If InStr(1, Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 2).Value, TextBox1.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        '* Change Sheet2 to the appropriate sheet code
        Sheet5.Cells(searchrow, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 1).Value
        Sheet5.Cells(searchrow, 2).Value = Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 2).Value
        Sheet5.Cells(searchrow, 3).Value = Sheet2.Cells(rownum, 3).Value
        searchrow = searchrow + 1
    End If
    rownum = rownum + 1
    Loop

If searchrow = 2 Then
MsgBox "Area not found"
Exit Sub
End If

'* change Sheet5 to the appropriate sheet code
ListBox2.RowSource = "Area_Search!a1:c" & Sheet5.Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
End Sub
```